# `siunitx` interferes with `array` and `tabular environment`

Tags: tables, siunitx, xparse

In the MWE below loading `siunitx` causes compile ERROR `! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\l_rn_tableFormat_tl): c' used`. I found that package `array` had recently been completely re-written, and besides, is in my `MiKTeX 2.9` distribution bundled with the standard `LaTeX tools`; eventually identified package `siunitx` to be the culprit.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 12 Nov 2017
%  `siunitx ` clashes with `array` and `tabular environment`.
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%  \usepackage{siunitx}  
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableFormat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableContent_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\myTable{}
  {
\group_begin:
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableFormat_tl {|c|c|c|c|}
%  Format:~\l_rn_tableFormat_tl\\  
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableHeader_tl {\hline \textbf{Item} & \textbf{col~1} & \textbf{col~2} & \textbf{col~3} \\\hline\hline}
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#1 &\textit{italic} &  $\alpha$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#2 & XYZ &  $\zeta$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#3 & 1 &  2 & a  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#4 & A &  Z & XX  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#5 & sdf &  wrtw45 & 54qge  \\\hline}
  \begin{tabular}{\l_rn_tableFormat_tl}
    \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
    \l_rn_tableContent_tl
  \end{tabular}
\group_end:
  }  %  \myTable
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myTable
\end{document}
```

Comment: nothing to do with `siunitx` just load `array` alone, you get the same error. As soon as `array` is loaded storing the arg to `table` in a macro has to be done in a very special way (that I don't remember). You might want to change the title of the question.

Comment: you have to use `\newcolumntype` _or_  get the macro expanded before `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: @daleif Confirmed, `array` produces the same error. Baffles me though that `array` does not even show up in my list of packages in `MiKTeX 2.9` and is described there as being bundled with the `Latex tools`, whatever that means.

Comment: @jfbu Can you show me the detail of (a) using `\newcolumntype` or (b) expand the macro before callin `\begin{tabular}. Thanks

Comment: Replace `\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableFormat_tl` by `\newcolumntype \l_rn_tableFormat_tl {|c|c|c|c|}`, suppress the `\tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableFormat_tl {|c|c|c|c|}`.

Comment: That I understand. But the whole purpose of the exercise is to automate table creation, and that includes assembling a `format` expression by generating the requisite number of `c|` terms from an argument passed by a `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: ... at this point `\newcolumntype` comes up with `! Undefined control sequence.` What package to I need to load?

Comment: `\newcolumntype` is defined by the `array` package

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `I found that package array had recently been completely re-written,`  It has had only a couple of very minor fixes since being released in its latex2e form in 1993

Comment: I am referring to `A new implementation of LATEX's tabular and array environment ... April 15, 2017` posted on CTAN. Although I suffer from frequent bouts of over-enthusiasm, the document looks fairly major to me.

Comment: ... with the answer supplied by @egreg which does everything I wanted to do, I won't need `\newcolumntype`.

Comment: The source `array.dtx` has `\date{Printed \today}`. Its "change log" most recent entry is from `2008/09/09` and the next one was from `1995/11/02`, both relating to doc changes. I see a `\MaintainedByLaTeXTeam{tools}` which possibly was added during the last ten years. Regarding `\newcolumntype`, you don't need it indeed if you expand the preambl, but you should load package `array` anyhow, because it modifies the way tabulars are horizontally spaced, so it is better to have it loaded, not to be surprised by the (not big) changes if one day you add a package which loads it for whatever reason.

Comment: correction: `\changes{v2.4d}{2016/10/06}{\cs{@halignto} set locally (pr/4488)}` is the latest one, as indicated by the package version number. The recapitulative list at top of the file starts at `v2.4c` from `2008/09/09` as mentioned in my prior comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `array` is loaded, `\begin{tabular}` performs no expansion of its mandatory argument, so this has to be done beforehand. With `expl3` it's a breeze.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 12 Nov 2017
%  `siunitx ` clashes with `array` and `tabular environment`.
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%  \usepackage{siunitx}  
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableFormat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableContent_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\myTable{}
  {
\group_begin:
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableFormat_tl {|c|c|c|c|}
%  Format:~\l_rn_tableFormat_tl\\  
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableHeader_tl {\hline \textbf{Item} & \textbf{col~1} & \textbf{col~2} & \textbf{col~3} \\\hline\hline}
  \tl_gset:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#1 &\textit{italic} &  $\alpha$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#2 & XYZ &  $\zeta$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#3 & 1 &  2 & a  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#4 & A &  Z & XX  \\\hline}
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\#5 & sdf &  wrtw45 & 54qge  \\\hline}
  \__rn_tablebegin:V \l_rn_tableFormat_tl % \begin{tabular}
    \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
    \l_rn_tableContent_tl
  \end{tabular}
\group_end:
  }  %  \myTable
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rn_tablebegin:n { \begin{tabular}{#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__rn_tablebegin:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myTable
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works without a glitch. However I am currently labouring on a problem regarding the generation of the `\l_rn_tableContent_tl` variable in a `\cs_` macro: what my macro returns seems right, has all the `&`, `double backslash` and `\hline` terms in the right places, yet, when I plug the variable into the `tabular environment`- regardless of whether `standard-tabular` or `egreg-tabular`, it shows the entire content of the variable as the first table entry. If I don't get on top of the problem soon I am afraid I will have to turn it into an MWE and post a new question.